# Yii active record find function class hinting

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm stuck using the old yii.
Its active record model can be used as follows:

```
class Booking extends CActiveRecord {
    /**
     * @param string $className
     * @return Booking
     */
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
    public function publish(){
       // code to publish the booking
    }

    // ... the rest of the generated code for the table

}

$model = Booking::model();
$model->getUnallocated();

$booking = $model->findByPk(815);
$booking->publish();
```

the problem is that the IDE (PhpStorm) does not allow me to ctrl+click the publish function in `$booking->publish()` because it does not know that the value returned by findByPk is a Booking instance.

I can fix this like follows

```
class Booking extends CActiveRecord {
    /**
     * @return Booking|null
     */
    public function findByPk($pk,$condition='',$params=array())
    {
        return parent::findByPk($pk,$condition,$params);
    }

    // ... the rest of the class
}
```

The problem is that this solution is not a clean one, now I have to define every fetching function `find`, `findAll`, `findByPk`... in every AR model class.

Another way to do it is like this

```
/** @var Booking $booking */
$booking = $model->findByPk(815);
```

But this has to be defined whenever it's used, which is also bothersome because it's used in many places.

Is there a clean way to this without adding as many method definitions?

Comment: Inline variable hinting? e.g. `/** @var Booking $booking */` before (or after) the `$booking = $model->findByPk(815);` line.

Comment: sorry, I added that it won't do 10 seconds after posting the question, you probably didn't notice it

Answer (score 0):

Time has passed, I found a solution

The trick is that you can return `@return static` in the comments, which is exactly what you need for PHPStorm to detect the correct class, so lets create a `BaseModel` that extends `CActiveRecord` and has the correct doc comments

So change `class MyClass extends CActiveRecord` with `class MyClass extends BaseModel`

while using this, now all the class hinting will work :)

```
<?php
/**
 * Extension of the default Yii Active Record class
 *
 * Edit this class to add custom behaviour to all the models used within the application
 *
 */

class BaseModel extends CActiveRecord
{

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * Uses the class that called the model() by default
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return static The static model class instance
     */
    public static function model($className = null)
    {
        return parent::model($className !== null ? $className : get_called_class());
    }

    /**
     * This function exists only to help the IDE autodetect the returned class
     * @param mixed $pk
     * @param string $condition
     * @param array $params
     * @return static
     */
    public function findByPk($pk,$condition='',$params=array())
    {
        return parent::findByPk($pk,$condition,$params);
    }

    /**
     * This function exists only to help the IDE autodetect the returned class
     * @param string $condition
     * @param array $params
     * @return static
     */
    public function find($condition='',$params=array())
    {
        return parent::find($condition,$params);
    }

    /**
     * This function exists only to help the IDE autodetect the returned class
     * @param string $condition
     * @param array $params
     * @return static[]
     */
    public function findAll($condition='',$params=array())
    {
        return parent::findAll($condition,$params);
    }

    /**
     * This function exists only to help the IDE autodetect the returned class
     * @param $pk
     * @param string $condition
     * @param array $params
     * @return static[]
     */
    public function findAllByPk($pk,$condition='',$params=array())
    {
        return parent::findAllByPk($pk,$condition,$params);
    }

    /**
     * This function exists only to help the IDE autodetect the returned class
     * @param $attributes
     * @param string $condition
     * @param array $params
     * @return static
     */
    public function findByAttributes($attributes,$condition='',$params=array())
    {
        return parent::findByAttributes($attributes,$condition,$params);
    }

    /**
     * This function exists only to help the IDE autodetect the returned class
     * @param $attributes
     * @param string $condition
     * @param array $params
     * @return static[]
     */
    public function findAllByAttributes($attributes,$condition='',$params=array())
    {
        return parent::findAllByAttributes($attributes,$condition,$params);
    }

    /**
     * This function exists only to help the IDE autodetect the returned class
     * @param $sql
     * @param array $params
     * @return static
     */
    public function findBySql($sql,$params=array())
    {
        return parent::findBySql($sql,$params);
    }

    /**
     * This function exists only to help the IDE autodetect the returned class
     * @param $sql
     * @param array $params
     * @return static[]
     */
    public function findAllBySql($sql,$params=array())
    {
        return parent::findAllBySql($sql,$params);
    }

    /**
     * This function exists only to help the IDE autodetect the returned class
     * This will add a couple of milliseconds with every `with` usage
     * @return static
     */
    public function with()
    {
        return call_user_func_array('parent::with', func_get_args());
    }

    /**
     * This function exists only to help the IDE autodetect the returned class
     * @return static
     */
    public function together()
    {
        return parent::together();
    }

}
```